# Cordova XapDeploy tool (XapDeployCmd.exe) didn't found

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, xap

I was creating a New Project Cordova project for windows phone 8 according to instructions in [this cordova oficial guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide).

After building project, when start emulator using "cordova emulate wp8" command it gives following error:

```
Running command: C:\Users\Amila\Desktop\projectCor\hello\platforms\wp8\cordova\r
un.bat --emulator

Building project: C:/Users/Amila/Desktop/projectCor/hello/platforms/wp8/HelloWor
ld.sln
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : any cpu
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  HelloWorld -> C:\Users\Amila\Desktop\projectCor\hello\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug
  \com.example.hello.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  No changes detected. Application manifest file is up to date
  Begin Xap packaging
  Creating file CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap
  Adding com.example.hello.dll
  Adding config.xml
  Adding www\cordova.js
  Adding www\cordova_plugins.js
  Adding www\css\index.css
  Adding www\img\logo.png
  Adding www\index.html
  Adding www\js\index.js
  Adding Images\appbar.back.rest.png
  Adding Images\appbar.close.rest.png
  Adding Images\appbar.feature.video.rest.png
  Adding Images\appbar.next.rest.png
  Adding Images\appbar.save.rest.png
  Adding Images\appbar.stop.rest.png
  Adding VERSION
  Adding SplashScreenImage.jpg
  Adding AppManifest.xaml
  Adding ApplicationIcon.png
  Adding Background.png
  Adding WMAppManifest.xml
  Xap packaging completed successfully

Deploying package to emulator
WARNING: XapDeploy tool (XapDeployCmd.exe) didn't found. Assume that it's in %PA
TH%
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn XapDeployCmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Error: C:\Users\Amila\Desktop\projectCor\hello\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat: Co
mmand failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Amila\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx

> Important Note: Command-line deployment for Windows Phone projects
>   requires Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. XapDeployCmd.exe is not included
>   in the version of Visual Studio 2012 that is installed by Windows
>   Phone SDK 8.0.